# How can we query for an UI element with more than one attribute in XCUITest

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I am facing issue while locating the UI elements on iOS app for my UI tests. The general strategy is to locate the element using a single attribute. Something like.
`XCUIApplication().staticTexts["Some text on the UI"]`
This gets you one matching element on the UI if present. Is there a way to query the UI using more than one attributes? Something like
`XCUIApplication().staticTexts[type ="Heading", value = "Some text on the UI"]`.
I want it to return an element rather than a query like `.matching()` does.

Comment: Where are you getting a `type` attribute from? A `staticText` typically only has a `label` and an `identifier` and they typically match. There are things called `accessibilityTraits`, but those are going to be somewhat difficult to work with. If you can provide a better example of what you're working with I'm sure we can find an answer by stringing multiple `matching()` together or using a predicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a predicate.  However, the fields you can rely on are fairly limited - I have no idea what this type=Heading is, but I don't believe you will be able to query on it.  You can query for the different XCUIElementTypes, but you have already cut your candidates down to only staticTexts here so that wouldn't help in this particular case.

Something like:

```
XCUIApplication().staticTexts.matching(NSPredicate(format: "value = 'Some text on the UI' or identifier = 'myIdentifier'")).firstMatch
```

Fields you can rely on are on XCUIElementAttributes: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes

Predicate programming guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks, David, this helps. I am glad I was going the right path. It's a bummer XCUITest has not many attributes to query on.